# Counting non zero values in a dictionary of arrays with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary of arrays

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, int[]> ret = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
    int[] a = {1,0,3,4,0};
    int[] b = { 3, 0, 9, 10, 0};
    int[] c = {2,3,3,5,0};
    ret.Add("Jack", a);
    ret.Add("Jane", b);
    ret.Add("James", c);

}
```

If I want to do an operation on the count of the columns such as `v*column count` I would do this:

```
        Dictionary<string, double[]> colcnt = ret.ToDictionary(r => r.Key,
                         r => r.Value.Select(v => v == 0 ? 0 :
                                  (double)v / (ret.Values.Count()) //equation
                                                   ).ToArray());
```

What is the LINQ code to perform operations such as count on rows with non zeros?

If I use a loop to count them it would be

```
        foreach (var item in ret)
        {
          int vals= item.Value.Count(s => s != 0);

        }
```

So if I were to do `v/column count` then all items in `a` would be divided by 3, all items in `b` would be divided by 3 and all items in `c` would be divided by 4

Comment: Why isn't your code enough? You are using linq quite well.

Comment: Do you want the total count of all rows, or an array of row counts?

Comment: @MatthewWatson count of the rows across (excluding values with 0)

Comment: What is exactly the mathematical equation you try to conduct?

Comment: @shay__ just simply divide each cell by the total number of non zero rows.

Comment: @ccsv The total number of non-zero rows altogether, or the number of non-zero rows in each array? You need to be more specific. ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson So it would be non zeros in each array so `a=3`,`b=3`,`c=4`

Comment: @ccsv I think I've understood what you want - see my updated answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
var result = ret.ToDictionary
(
    r => r.Key, 
    v => v.Value.Select(n => (double)n/v.Value.Count(i => i != 0)).ToArray()
);
```

This will set the values to `NaN` for a row if all the elements of that row are zero. If instead you want to make the results for that row zero, you could change the code to:

```
var result = ret.ToDictionary
(
    r => r.Key, 
    v => v.Value.Select(n =>
    {
        double count = v.Value.Count(i => i != 0);
        return (count > 0) ? n/count : 0.0;
    }).ToArray()
);
```

Comment: not really a sum but a count so row a = 3, b=3, c=4. If I were to do a for loop over the dictionary I would do `item.Value.Count(s => s != 0)`

Comment: Thanks for the  `NaN` setting

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a sum of all non zero values in all the dictionary items you can use

```
ret.Sum(x => x.Value.Count(y => y != 0));
```

If you need to iterate through all the key value pairs and you wish not to use a foreach loop then you have to come up with an extension method of your own as shown below

```
 public static class DictionaryExtensionMethods
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> method)
    {
        foreach (T obj in enumerable)
        {
            method(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       var ret = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
        int[] a = { 1, 0, 3, 4, 0 };
        int[] b = { 3, 0, 9, 10, 0 };
        int[] c = { 2, 3, 3, 5, 0 };
        ret.Add("Jack", a);
        ret.Add("Jane", b);
        ret.Add("James", c);
        ret.ForEach(x => Write(x.Value.Count(y => y !=0), x.Key));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Write(int count, string key)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Count of non zeroes in {0} is {1}", key, count);
    }
}
```